# I don't seem to have an ASPNET user account running on my machine

Tags: asp.net

Hi: I'm reading up on ASP.NET, and just came to a chapter that explains how to upload a file to your website. It says that in order to save a file to your file system, in the case of every OS except Win Server '03, an ASP.NET page executes in the security context of the ASPNET account. I don't have an ASPNET account running on my machine (win xp pro sp3; .NET 3.5). The program runs fine, by the way, I'm just trying to understand what an ASPNET account is exactly, and why it doesn't seem to show up on my list of user accounts. Thanks.

Comment: It's jsut an account like any other Windows account. Where are you looking for it?

Comment: From what I've read, I get that it's just a Windows account, but I thought there was more to this account because it exists (as i understand it) for ASP.NET to launch it's sites within it. I'm looking for the ASPNET account in my Control Panel, under User Accounts. I was also looking for it under the security tab of the properties dialog box of any folder you right-click on. Couldn't find it though, but I know it's there. (see my accepted answer below)

Comment: When you run app aspnet_regiis.exe in the Framework folder 
in itcreates the ASPNET account Obiviuosly you need IIS installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASPNET is only used if use IIS. This was the norm in ASP.Net 1.1

However in new versions of Visual Studio IIS is not needed, so it uses an internal web server.

If ASPNET exists in a command window ( Start -> Run cmd Clikc OK) type and press enter

```
    net user ASPNET
```

you should see the details of the account and in Task Manager you will see a process asp_wp.exe

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks for that. I actually read somewhere that VS uses an internal web server. Whenever I run a site from VS(visual web dev 2010 actually) I get an icon placed in my task bar for an app called, ASP.NET Development Server. Is this that internal web server program? When I use VS 05 at work, I don't think that icon pops up, at least I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1):

File Access

The **Network Service account** has Read and Execute permissions on the IIS server root folder by default. The IIS server root folder is named Wwwroot. This means that an ASP.NET application deployed inside the root folder already has Read and Execute permissions to its application folders. However, if your ASP.NET application needs to use files or folders in other locations, you must specifically enable access.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx

Comment: ... what question are you answering?